# Return a list of averages LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to make a suggestion system on my restaurant review site. It gets the average score of all reviews of a certain restaurant and then finds the average review score from all of the other restaurants that have the same cuisine as the original restaurant. It returns a list of restaurants with the same cuisine that have a greater review average than the original restaurant. It then saves the list to the database.

I have tried to create the query in linq but I keep on recieving errors such as `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'int'` or the results of the query are wrong.

Any help would be greatful.

**Error Line**

```
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid)
    .Average(r => r.score);
```

**Suggestion Function**

```
var averagescore = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => r.RestaurantId == review.RestaurantId)
    .Average(r => r.score);

var getrestaurantsid = (from r in db.Reviews
                       where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
                       select r.RestaurantId).ToList();
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid)
    .Average(r => r.score);

var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
               where getrestaurantaverage >= averagescore
               select r.RestaurantId).ToList();
foreach (var item in choices)
{
    var suggestion = new Suggestion()
    {
        reviewid = review.id,
        Userid = review.UserId,
        restaurantid = item
    };
    db.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Review");
```

Comment: Which line give you an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid)` tries to compare an `int` id with a list. If you want to find resturants whose IDs are in the list, do this:

```
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => getrestaurantsid.Contains(r.RestaurantId))
    .Average(r => r.score);
```

---

To get the average of each individual restaurant, you could create an anonymous type

```
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => getrestaurantsid.Contains(r.RestaurantId))
    .GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantId)
    .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Average = g.Average(r => r.score) });

foreach (var x in getrestaurantaverage) {
    Console.WriteLine("Restaurant = {0}, average = {1}", x.ID, x.Average);
}
```

This gives you the average per restaurant ID.

---

However there is no need to get a list of restaurant ids beforehand, do it directly

```
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews
    .Where(r => r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine)
    .GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantId)
    .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Average = g.Average(r => r.score) });
```

Comment: Will give you average of all restaurants put together.

Comment: All restaurants contained in the list `getrestaurantsid`, because `Average` gets an enumeration filtered by the preceeding `Where`.

Comment: How would I get the average of each individual restaurant?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're making far too many DB calls to get all necessary data. You should probably try to merge all these queries into one:

```
from r in db.Reviews
where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
group r by r.RestaurantId into g
where g.Average(x => x.Score) >= db.Reviews.Where(r => r.RestaurantId == review.RestaurantId).Average(x => x.Score)
select g.Key
```

Comment: +1 as this query is somewhat better than mine.  I won't delete my answer simply because this answer doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with your code is right here:

```
.Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid)
```

`getrestaurantsid` is a *list of values* not *one* value.

We can change this, but your problems are more significant.  `getrestaurantaverage` cannot be just one query, with your general approach, you need to do it, *for each id in `getrestaurantsid`:

```
foreach var restaurantID in getrestaurantsid)
{
    var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid).Average(r => r.score);

    var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
                   where getrestaurantaverage >= averagescore
                   select r.RestaurantId).ToList();
    foreach (var item in choices)
    {
        var suggestion = new Suggestion()
        {
            reviewid = review.id,
            Userid = review.UserId,
            restaurantid = item
        };
        db.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

But this is *super* inefficient.  You're now executing *lots* and *lots* of different DB queries.  We can simplify this whole thing a *lot*.

```
var reviewAverages = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine)
    .GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantId)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Average(r => r.score);

var myAverage = reviewAverages[review.RestaurantId];
var choices = reviewAverages.Where(pair => pair.Value >= myAverage);
```

And that's it.  One single DB query, and only a few lines of code.

Comment: Doesn't check `Cuisine` equality. Will also get all the averages to application, when you can make `>= myAverage` at DB too.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
var getrestaurantsid = (from r in db.Reviews
                       where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
                       select r.RestaurantId).ToList();
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.RestaurantId = getrestaurantsid).Average(r => r.score);
```

getrestaurantsid is of type `List<int>`, so the expression in the `Where` function below it is not going to work.

I suggest something more like this:

```
var getrestaurantaverage = db.Reviews.Where(r => getrestaurantsid.Contains(r.RestaurantId)).Average(r => r.score);
```

Comment: Will give you average of all restaurants put together.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I assumed that's what OP was looking for.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll No, he's looking for all restaurants with a better average than a given restaurant.  He needs the average of *each* restaurant, which is what that particular query is intended to grab.